# How to batch rename files from path to filename

Tags: sed, find, rename

I'd like to:

```
find /dir -type f
/dir/2008/12/10/21_13_026.jpg
/dir/2008/09/16/01_53_012.jpg
/dir/2008/09/16/01_52_011.jpg
/dir/2008/09/16/01_54_013.jpg
/dir/2008/09/16/01_56_015.jpg
/dir/2008/09/16/01_58_016.jpg
/dir/2008/09/16/01_55_014.jpg
/dir/2008/09/16/01_51_010.jpg
/dir/2008/09/09/17_17_008.jpg
/dir/2008/09/25/17_02_001.jpg
/dir/2008/09/25/18_35_002.jpg
/dir/2008/09/15/22_59_005.jpg
/dir/2008/09/15/22_57_007.jpg
/dir/2008/09/15/22_56_009.jpg
/dir/2008/09/15/22_58_006.jpg
/dir/2008/09/15/23_02_003.jpg
/dir/2008/09/15/22_53_008.jpg
/dir/2008/09/15/23_00_004.jpg
/dir/2008/09/01/18_50_013.jpg
```

Then rename each file to the output it's respective line in the find result, but replacing the / with a -

something like:

```
find /dir -type f -exec rename {} sed -i 's/\//-/g' \;
```

The point is to rename each file from

```
/dir/2008/09/15/23_00_004.jpg
```

to

```
-dir-2008-09-15-23_00_004.jpg
```

but my syntax and execution of rename isn't right. any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: `/` is used for moving to desired path. It's not the part of a file-name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```sh
find /dir -type f -exec rename 's|/|-|g' {} \;
```